# Why is baking soda good at dissolving grease?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can someone please explain why baking soda is good at dissolving grease?
Thanks,

Comment: It is not so much about dissolving as it is about surface tension.

Comment: @IvanNeretin How does surface tension come into play? Boiling baking soda in a dirty pan lifts black grease that could not be removed by detergents.

Comment: How is this off topic? How sodium bicarbonate could produce the same (or better) macroscopic results as a nonionic surfactant while not being a surfactant itself is definitely a chemistry question!

Answer (score 1):

> Baking soda is an alkali, so it dissolves grease very well.

[Source](https://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/household-hints-tips/cleaning-organizing/5-great-ways-to-clean-grease2.htm)

> Alkalies are good grease removers because the alkalies form an emulsion, a mixture where oily or solid particles are held in suspension. The particles do not separate from the rest of the liquid; therefore, they are not redeposited on the surface being cleaned.

[Source](https://cleanj10.imascientist.org.uk/question/why-do-alkalis-clean-better-than-acidswhy-do-the-police-use-coke-to-clean-away-blood)

> Alkaline cleaners work well because they emulsify grease. Fatty acids are normally insoluble which is why they cannot be cleaned using water alone. The alkaline breaks down fat making them dispersible in water.

[Source](http://plasticisrubbish.com/2014/03/23/rivers-of-filth/)